# "The way [the] control of the behemoth would be shared"

Tags: definite-articles

> Sechin strictly follows Putin's instructions but also appears to influence the president. Industry sources say that in 2005 Sechin blocked plans that Putin had blessed for Rosneft to merge with Gazprom (GAZP.ME) because he did not like the way **control** of the behemoth would be shared.

[Source](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/putins-oil-tsar-emerged-shadows-155108711.html).

Why do you think the author didn't use a definite article with *control*?

Comment: Why do you think there ought to be the definite article? There's no need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"control" is, in this case, a mass noun, and thus, the definite article can often be omitted.

Answer (score -5):

A definite article should be used before specific abstract nouns. I think that this is a mistake.

Comment: I disagree. You would never say that Putin "seized the control of Gazprom."